# How to calculate total sales with different reference types

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have these tables:

```
Stories
- id
Chapter
- id
- story_id
Payments
- id
- type
- reference_id
- reference_type
- amount
```

I calculate the total sales of the Story with :

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$weekStartDate = ->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$weekEndDate = $now->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');

Story::join('payments', 'stories.id', '=', 'payments.reference_id')
            ->groupBy('stories.id')
            ->whereNotNull('payments.amount')
            ->whereIn('payments.transaction', ['DONATE', 'COMBO', 'BUY'])
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where(function ($subquery) {
                    $subquery->where('payments.reference_type', '=', Story::class);
                })->orWhere(function ($subquery) {
                    $subquery->whereIn(
                        'payments.reference_id',
                        Chapter::select('id')->where('story_id', 'stories.id')
                    )->where('payments.reference_type', '=', Chapter::class);
                });
            })
        ->where('payments.created_at', '>=', $weekStartDate)
        ->where('payments.created_at', '<=', $weekEndDate)
        ->select(
        'stories.id', 'stories.name', 'stories.image','stories.introduce',
            DB::raw('sum(payments.amount) as total')
        )
        ->orderBy('total', 'desc')->get();
```

But for stories with Buy transaction with reference_type = Chapter::class, it is not counted. Can anyone help me with the exact calculation?